# ERROR 1047 (08S01): WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use

Tags: mysql, clustering, galera

I have 3 node MySQL Galera cluster in Production, Today when we hit large DDoS on our network cause some issue and assuming some kind of network separation caused following issue on node-1

`ERROR 1047 (08S01): WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use`

node-2 and node-3 is working fine. in this condition what option i have to fix node-1 only without creating any chaos?

I did google and people only giving example of 2 node cluster but in my case its 3 node and its functional at present so i don't want to bootstrap again, what is the safe way to bring this node back into cluster?

This is the status of above node

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                 |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.130673                                              |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000010                                              |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.413593                                              |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 95.591121                                             |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 454                                                   |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 6.275534                                              |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 146                                                   |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                     |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | f0d74456-9803-11e8-be49-6a9820bd29f8                  |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                               |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000002                                              |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.267027                                              |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                    |
| wsrep_desync_count           | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                       |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                       |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0/0/0/0/0                                             |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                           |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.059237                                              |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 322079243575550                                       |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 3556809                                               |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 372                                                   |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | cca74c82-8346-11eb-931e-b7df128f4e5d                  |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 172.28.1.216:3306,172.28.1.236:3306,172.28.1.183:3306 |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 3947799887                                            |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 18446744073709551615                                  |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_index            | 2                                                     |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 2148340                                               |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 7779.915248                                           |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 2148340                                               |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 1                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_state            | 1                                                     |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Joining: receiving State Transfer                     |
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | f0d74456-9803-11e8-be49-6a9820bd29f8                  |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 7                                                     |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                     |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 25.3.22(r3764)                                        |
| wsrep_ready                  | OFF                                                   |
| wsrep_received               | 294474146                                             |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 631142924318                                          |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_replicated             | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 17                                                    |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
58 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Solution: my node-2 and node-3 was in synced and health so in above case i just reboot my node-1 which was bad and that fixed my issue.